# in SSRS how to split the value of a long string into two seperate text box

Tags: reporting-services

i have the expression like this
=First(Fields!Moneyword.Value, "OfficialReceipts")

for example the moneyword has a value of "five hundred twenty-five thousand four hundred eighty-five"
and i want to seperate
"five hundred twenty-five thousand"
and
"four hundred eighty-five"
into two seperate text box

i try something like this
=Split(First(Fields!Moneyword.Value, "OfficialReceipts"))(0).ToString()
but it only return the word after the first word

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is determine the logic that you can apply to always break at the correct point. This is quite tricky because you don't know what units (hundreds, thousands etc.) will be present. If you have the original numeric value it might be easier to use that to accomplish this.

Anyway, based on your single example I used the position of the last "hundred" word, then looked for the preceding word and used that as the point to split. As I said thought this is not going to work in some cases for example if the number was 123050.

It might point you in the right direction for a more complete method. You might also wan to consider some custom code for this.

So, for the left part you can use this.

```
=LEFT(
    Fields!Moneyword.Value, 
    InStrRev(Fields!Moneyword.Value, 
             " ", 
             InStrRev(Fields!Moneyword.Value, " hundred") -1
             )
    )
```

Starting in the middle and working outwards, we look for the last instance of the string `" hundred"` (notice the preceding space). Then, from this point in the string, we look for the first space. This space is the point at which we want to split the string.

SO no it's just a case of taking the left *n* number of characters, where *n* is the number we got above.

and for the right part, we just take the section of the string that starts at our split point, like this.

```
=Mid(
    Fields!Moneyword.Value, 
    InStrRev(Fields!Moneyword.Value, " ", InStrRev(Fields!Moneyword.Value, " hundred")-1)
    )
```